# How do you convert ttf font to pff2?

Tags: truetype, theming

I'm looking into grub2 themes, and i can't seem to convert ttf to grub's native format.

I tried to do this:

```
➜  asdfafdsgsgsg  ttf2bdf -p 32 Oxygen_Regular_Oxygen.ttf > oxygen.bdf
➜  asdfafdsgsgsg  grub-mkfont -s 32 -o oxygen.pf2 oxygen.bdf          
grub-mkfont: error: can't set 32x32 font size.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generating Grub2 PF2 fonts requires significant patience, as I had to attempt the conversion multiple times.

If your going from TTF -> PF2, you should first try skipping the BDF intermediate stage. Something like this command,

```
grub2-mkfont -o ./oxygen.pf2 -s 24 ./Oxygen_Regular_Oxygen.ttf
```

If it was only the `-p 32` which caused that error, I would accept that output at face value.  Unless you know of other fonts, which successfully specified such a large point size.  Additionally I would hope `grub-mkfont` wouldn't be allowed to generate a font, whose size exceeds Grub2 limitations.  However I should mention, `grub-mkfont` historically had been lacking in proper maintenance.  This might not currently be the case, and would expect upstream has rectified this long ago, but distributions often lag behind.